# RunUnitTests error after Xcode 5 update

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xcode5

All I did was to update the project to Xcode 5. Now when I try to run tests I am getting this error

```
if [ "${TEST_AFTER_BUILD}" = "YES" ]; then
    Error ${LINENO} "RunUnitTests is obsolete. To run unit tests for your target, use the Test scheme action in the Xcode IDE and the test action in xcodebuild."
    Note ${LINENO} "You can remove the Run Script build phase that invokes RunUnitTests from your unit test bundle target."
    # Exit with EX_UNAVAILABLE to indicate that this subsystem is unavailable.
    exit 69
fi
```

Where `Error ${LINENO} "RunUnitTests is obsolete. To run unit tests for your target, use the Test scheme action in the Xcode IDE and the test action in xcodebuild."` is highlighted red. I googled this problem but could not find any answer. What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most likely have the build setting Test After Build set to YES. Xcode 5 does not support the Test After Build build setting. Set Test After Build to NO and the error should go away.

Comment: This option doesn't show up in the UI in Xcode 5 anymore. It's now a User-defined setting called "TEST_AFTER_BUILD".

Answer (score 2):

Use this command.

`xcodebuild test -scheme <YOUR SCHEME NAME HERE> -destination OS=6.1,name=iPhone`

I also googled and find this site.
http://petosoft.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/running-unit-tests-using-jenkins-and-xcodebuild-on-xcode-5-0/

Comment: Please enclose all inline code blocks within ` for them to be formatted as code. For multi-line codes either indent them by 4 spaces (or) use the `{}` button in the button bar. Other thing, rather than posting a link please post its essential contents also into the answer. This will make sure that your answer wouldn't lose its worth even if the link becomes inactive.

Answer (score 1):

The TEST_AFTER_BUILD option becomes user defined settings in Xcode 5. Just delete it will be ok.